# Persistent network share connection not working with runas

Tags: windows-xp, network-share

If I use `runas /user:DOMAIN\user cmd.exe` (using XP), previously mapped persistent network drives are considered unavailable. `net use` shows:

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  H:        \\SERVER\SHARE            Microsoft Windows Network
```

`dir H:` fails with "The system cannot find the path specified.".

The connection is easily revived with `NET USE H: \SERVER\SHARE': not asked for a password when I do this. What is going on? Can I make Windows safely revive this drive automatically when it is first accessed.

Comment: did you create the persistent mapping in the DOMAIN\user's context? i.e. did you do a `runas /user:DOMAIN\user /profile "net use h: \\server\share /persist"´ or something equivalent beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `runas` does not load a user's profile by default, you might have more luck when supplying the `/profile` option to `runas`. You also might be running into the problem that mapped drives connected in a specific user's context are unavailable to others. Quoting from the MSDN documentation for Windows XP:

> Drive letters are not global to the system. Each logon session receives its own set of drive letters from A to Z. Therefore, redirected drives cannot be shared between processes running under different user accounts.  Moreover, a service (or any process running within its own logon session) cannot access the drive letters that were established within a different logon session.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143(v=vs.85).aspx

This is by design and cannot be changed.

Comment: The letters do appear in `NET USE` so I have a hard time believing the are usable. Unfortunately, the `/profile` option did not help. I did see that documentation, but I have yet to get a good explanation of what exactly is going on.